# align two labels text vertically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6

I have 2 labels with text as

```
First Value :1,000       
Second Value :100
```

How can I vertically align two `UILabels` text to achieve like below(i.e to make the labels text align vertically at colon).

```
 First Value :1,000  
Second Value :100
```

I know that it is possible with 4 different labels.

First Label1 : amount label1
Second Label2 : amount Label2
But,what i need is to achieve them in 2 labels only

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"First Label1: %@",amount label1];         
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"First Label2: %@",amount label2];
```

and align vertically at colon

Comment: This is almost impossible. You need 4 labels to get this right. Otherwise it will cause more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: yes, i know.Is there any possibilities?

Comment: Just use four labels Siva, Otherwise you will have to write a load of code to know where the colons are and manually adjust your label's positions. What could possibly be the reason you can't use four labels?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by using AutoLayout. You will need 4 labels:

**Title Labels**

*'First Value'* (Right Aligned)

*'Second Value'* (Right Aligned)

**Value Labels**

*':1,000'* (Left Aligned)

*':100'* (Left Aligned)

You will need to pin both title labels to have equal widths and you will need to pin both value labels to have equal widths.

You will also need to set constraints for horizontal spacing between both title and value. To ensure that the spacing is always equal between rows.

In code when you set the value of your label, you will need to make sure that the colon symbol is part of the value. E.g. `[NSString stringwithFormat:@":%d", value];`

This image illustrates the constraints required:

[image]

Comment: it is possible by 4 labels,but i have to use 2 labels only

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use 4? I can't think of one, from the end user's point of view it wouldn't be noticed, and from a technical point of view I don't see why either?

Answer (score 0):

Using Autolayout place the two labels in the UIView and then align the view to align centre in the horizontal and use vertical spacing between the views ... as

The correct approach is to use a container view, which derives its height from its subviews. The container view is then pinned to the centre of the cell - you wouldn't have any constraints linking the container to the top and bottom edges of the cell.

Within the container, the vertical constraints would be |[label1]-[label2]|, which would make the container the height of the two labels plus the space, and the centre of the container view would be between the two labels.[image: use two labels and then use verti]